# Email templates design messed up after upgrading to magento 2.4.4

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.4

I am upgrading my website from Magento 2.4.3 to 2.4.4
After upgrade I have found out that email templates design have messed up. Earlier the email templates have a fixed width and was aligned at the center of the page.
But in 2.4.4 I have found out that there is no fixed width given to the email templates and the design is also messed up.

Screenshot of Order confirmation email template from old version i.e Magento 2.4.3
You can see that the email template is properly designed and at the center of the page.

[image]

Screenshot of email template after upgrade to 2.4.4.

[image]

We can see the email template has no styling and also the product and price detail section is messed up. I tried to google regarding this issue but could not find anything.

Could anyone please suggest that will I have to write the css to make it look similar to magento 2.4.3 or is there a way or some patch available by magento to fix the email template design.
The same issue is also with other email template like Shipment email template, creditmemo templates.

Screenshot of shipment mails from magento 2.4.4

[image]

Screenshot of shipment mails from 2.4.3

[image]

Could anyone please suggest why all the email templates are messed up in 2.4.4

I feel there might be some easy solution for this as writing css for all the email templates could take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Magento default code did not had any problem. We have overridden the default header and footer phtml file for emails in our custom theme that caused the issue.
We have deleted it now and the design is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Open the email template files in your directory and then open header.html and footer.html and add the below code.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```